# Can we use the lagrange multipliers in iterative way?

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, convex-optimization

I have a question, I tried to google it, but I am not sure yet.

The question is, can we use the Lagrange multipliers in iterative update instead of stochastic gradient descent in order to optimize any function?

For example, I used to work on optimizing such function in iterative way using the SGD in order to optimize such parameters, and the optimization is working well.  So I decided to extend that function to add a constraint for that function, is it possible in all ways to  use Lagrange multipliers instead of SGD as long as we have constraints? Then update the function in iterative way.

if you have easy documents which explain that point, it will be appreciated to help me.

thank you so much in advance.

Comment: In convex optimization the Lagrange multipliers are the optimal variables for the dual problem. There are many primal-dual algorithms that simultaneously solve the primal and the dual problem. In such algorithms, both the primal variables and the dual variables (Lagrange multipliers) are updated iteratively. The augmented Lagrangian method is one example of a method like this. By the way, I'd be interested in seeing your optimization problem if you feel like writing it out.

Comment: @littleO  ,  Briefly, the cost function is J = {|(J1)  - (J2)|}.^2 , where J1 = min(xy) and J2 = min(zt). So what I made till now is to optimize the difference (the error) between the minimum of xy and zy with respect to x, y, z and t to make them almost equals. in another way, J = {|min(xy)  - min(zt)|}.^2 . my question is, I need to add a constraint that x - z = 0 ,  in every step of optimization, I need to keep x = z. Can I make that using the Lagrange multipliers? of there is another way I can make it? thank you so much

Comment: Sorry I haven't had time to think about this more carefully. Are $x$ and $y$ scalars? When you write $\min(xy)$, is $xy$ the product of $x$ and $y$? (If so, what do you mean by $\min(xy)$. Do you perhaps mean $\min(x,y)$ instead?)

Comment: @littleO yes, x and y scalars. so I optimize them, then compare it with min(zt). so I was wondering if we can use a Lagrange multipliers with constraint of x - z = 0. or we can use another iterative method to optimize that including the x = z.

Comment: @littleO is it possible to have your contact?, do you have an email, or whatsapp or anything else we can contact instantaneously.

Comment: The expression $\min(zt)$ doesn't make sense because $zt$ is just a scalar. It's like if I wrote $\min(5)$. Do you mean $\min(z,t)$ instead?  That would mean we're taking the minimum of the two numbers $z$ and $t$.

Comment: @littleO   Oh, I'm really so sorry for the mistake I made.  The x, y, z and t are vectors .. they are not scalar. So sorry for that bit mistake. So that, I'm minimizing the error of the two optimal values. the min of product xy and the product zt

Comment: So to summarize, the min(xy) is the product of x and y, and I minimize that by iterative method. also for min(zt). then I minimize the difference between the two optimal value in order to get the optimal cost function. so what I need is to add a constraint of vector x = vector z .  @littleO please let me see your opinion when you have time..  I'm waiting.

Comment: Hmm, I think the problem has not been stated in a way that makes sense. For example, if $J_1$ is a function, it's not clear what the inputs to the function $J_1$ are. And it appears that $J_1$ should be equal to $-\infty$, the way things are stated now. I don't think I'll have much more time to look at this, hopefully someone else will be able to help.